# Are the crowns you earn for winning worth more than 1?

Tags: fall-guys-ultimate-knockout

Due to daily challenges, you can usually get a crown pretty easily even if you don't win, which makes me wonder.  If I win a match and grab the crown, will this still only be worth as much as one I might get by earning fame or doing daily challenges, or will it be worth more?  (I haven't won a game yet)

please comment if this is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I earned my first crown, and I can confirm that it is no more valuable than the ones you earn from pieces or fame.